# Extractor Functions in lme4 Misfunctioning?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to understand the linear algebra operations behind the `lmer` function in `R`, and I found what seemed to be a great resource on-line on a [lecture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.wisc.edu%2F~bates%2FPotsdamGLMM%2FLMMD.pdf&ei=_oxvVZ_POI71yATSi4I4&usg=AFQjCNFJyW3K10nLDRBmcRwPudsrrSnElg&bvm=bv.94911696,d.aWw) given by the creator of the `lme4` package, Douglas Bates.

The example deals with the dataset *Dyestuff* and calls for a mixed-effects model as follows:

```
fm1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1 + (1 | Batch), Dyestuff)
```

The following slides include lines of code to extract the underlying matrices for the random effects, such as:

```
efm1 <- expand(fm1)
efm1$S
6 x 6 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"

#       [,1]      [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]
[1,]  0.84823       .       .       .       .       .
[2,]       .  0.84823       .       .       .       .
[3,]       .       .  0.84823       .       .       .
[4,]       .       .       .  0.84823       .       .
[5,]       .       .       .       .  0.84823       .
[6,]       .       .       .       .       .  0.84823
```

and,

```
efm1$T6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
[1,] 1 . . . . .
[2,] . 1 . . . .
[3,] . . 1 . . .
[4,] . . . 1 . .
[5,] . . . . 1 .
[6,] . . . . . 1
```

or,

```
(fm1S <- tcrossprod(efm1$T %*% efm1$S))

6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"

[1,] 0.71949 .       .       .       .       .
[2,] .       0.71949 .       .       .       .
[3,] .       .       0.71949 .       .       .
[4,] .       .       .       0.71949 .       .
[5,] .       .       .       .       0.71949 .
[6,] .       .       .       .       .       0.71949
```

Yet, when I try to run the same line codes on R, I get the following error messages:

```
efm1 <- expand(fm1)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘expand’ for signature ‘"lmerMod"’
```

and not surprisingly,

```
efm1$S
Error: object 'efm1' not found
```

Doing a `?expand` identifies this function as still existing, and seemingly meant to produce matrix decompositions, such as LU or RQ.

Doing a search on-line, I found out that Douglas is using now *Julia* (can the next statistical language have a less implausible name? No, not "Pied Pier"! Sorry, I digress...).

What am I doing wrong? Is the `lme4` now orphan and in decay? Is there a typo in the slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at very old slides.

- a full description of the linear mixed model capabilities of the package, including details of the internal representation, is [on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5823), in press in *J. Stat. Software* (a reference to this information is also in the [citation information for the package on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/citation.html)).  (We're still working on the paper that describes the GLMM capabilities.)
- the `getME()` function is the current recommended method for accessing model information.
- `lme4` is still under fairly active development [on github](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/).
- Doug Bates is indeed more interested in [building mixed model frameworks in Julia now](https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl), but he still participates in `lme4` maintenance to some extent.

The notation/internal representation has changed somewhat, but reconstructing the variance-covariance matrix from internal information can be done as follows (the internal `Lambdat` is equivalent to `t(T %*% S)` in the old notation).

```
library("lme4")
fm1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1 + (1 | Batch), Dyestuff)
crossprod(getME(fm1,"Lambdat"))
```